# How to check if id exist before push in async npm node js

Tags: node.js

```
let taskQueue = async.queue(async ({url,id}, callback) => {
  callback();
}, 5);

taskQueue.push({ name: element.name, id: element.id });
```

How can I check if **id** exist before to push to queue.

The documentation of async npm is hard to understand...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way! You'll probably have to do it yourself.

```
const queuedTasks = {};
let taskQueue = async.queue(async ({url,id}, callback) => {
  callback();
}, 5);

const task = { name: element.name, id: element.id };

if(queuedTasks[task.id] !== void 0) {
  queuedTasks[task.id] = true;
  taskQueue.push(task, function onComplete() { delete queuedTasks[task.id]; });
}
```